# Domdocument Load not loading

Tags: php, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to load xml file through url(i.e. rss).
But when I Use

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
if($doc->load($url,LIBXML_NOWARNING)===false)  
{   
    echo "Hello";
    //echo @$doc->load($url,LIBXML_NOWARNING);
    //exit;
    $error = $doc->load($url);
    print_r($error);exit;
}
```

It only prints Hello..
No warning displayed for line 2.

Please provide me solution that which error occurs as I am getting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the rendered content is not visible. Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on your browser.

Also, instead of `print_r` try with `var_dump`

```
 $error = $doc->load($url);
         var_dump($error);
```

**EDIT :**

So it seems like your `$doc->load` failed in the first place. You need to change your `if` statement to

```
if($doc->load($url,LIBXML_NOWARNING)===true) // Replaced false with true.
```

or simply

```
if($doc->load($url,LIBXML_NOWARNING))
```

Your XML load failed that's why it went inside the `if` statement. Check whether the URL is spelled right or check if the URL **really** exists.

Comment: okay, by using var_dump.... it shows bool(false). I am trying to find out what is the error.

Comment: Could you tell me if it gets failed at line 2 then why it doesnot showing any error?

Comment: Can you share the URL here ?

Comment: oh! I find out what is the problem RSS source code contains special character at line 82. Could you help how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exit;`  from the code after `echo "Hello";` that is the reason

Comment: Oh Sorry.. Just a typo mistake... I commented exit after echo "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Try using `libxml_use_internal_errors()` to capture XML parsing errors:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = true;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$url = 'http://page2rss.com/rss/91a83628a27c43b6ab4f0b3959f69f5a';
$doc->load($url);

$errors = libxml_get_errors();

foreach ($errors as $error) {
    printf("Error %d at line %d, column %d:\n\t%s\n",
        $error->code, $error->line, $error->column, $error->message);
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

// Error 9 at line 82, column 155:
//     Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
// Bytes: 0xAE 0x20 0x28 0x52
```